# How do I create a Swing overlay (JPanel) on top of an AWT container?

Tags: java, swing, awt, overlay

I want to create a Swing overlay on top of an AWT Applet.

The AWT applet is external, so I cannot update it to use Swing components. I have tried using an `OverlayLayout` JPanel as the content pane in my JFrame, adding my overlay JPanel and the AWT container to it (in that order).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
}

private void createAndShowGui() {
    JFrame window = new JFrame("My Window");
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel content = new JPanel();
    content.setLayout(new OverlayLayout(content));

    JPanel overlayLayer = new JPanel();
    overlayLayer.setLayout(null);
    overlayLayer.setOpaque(false);

    Container applet = new Container();
    applet.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    applet.setPreferredSize(800, 600);

    content.add(overlayLayer);
    content.add(applet);

    window.setContentPane(content);
    window.pack();
    window.setVisible(true);
}
```

I expect to see a black background, since the overlay is transparent, but it's grey (the default). Changing the `Container` to a `JPanel` results in a black background.

EDIT:
It seems like Container does not show the background color even if you add it directly as the content pane, but using a Panel does. Still, adding a JPanel on top of it does not result in a black background.

Comment: If it's using native components (AWT) then you're going to have a hard time making it work, as AWT doesn't have a concept of Z-Ordering like Swing does

Comment: @MadProgrammer Is there any way to make it work, or am I out of luck? I suppose I could intercept the AWT paint call and draw directly on the Applet canvas, but I'm not sure it's a good option.

Comment: Generally speaking, you're out of luck on most fronts. AWT is not only of date, but Applets are also deprecated